# How to upload file from any folder in sd card to server using Android Phonegap

Tags: android, file-upload, cordova

I am getting error message "Object object". I have a folder in sd card. I want to upload this to server. I have a upload.php in my server.

```
    function local() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///TestFolder/1.jpg", uploadOffline, fail);
    }
    function uploadOffline(fileEntry){
    checkConnection();

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test1";
    params.value2 = "param1";

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    var uri = fileEntry.toURI();
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(uri, "http://www.myurl.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to upload log files. You have to change the path of the file and server address.
If you don't know the ip address 10.0.2.2 is android alias for your localhost. I got this method from some other site. I just changed the file path and server address.

```
private void uploadMedia() throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile ="/data/data/com.jos.finalsolution/files/LocationData";
    String urlServer = "http://10.0.2.2/phpvt/receiver.php";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));
    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    //Exception handling
    }

}
```

Comment: This is java code. I am using Phonegap so i need javascript code. My code that i wrote above is working for capture and upload photo. I've made some changes for upload photo from SD card. But i think i'm missing something.

Comment: Hi, i am wondering what does the maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024; do

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you found the solution to your problem, but maybe this codes will help you.

```
function files() {
    alert("Let's Start")    
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
        function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            fileSys = fileSystem;
        }
        , fsFail);

    fileSys.root.getDirectory("myFolder/", {create: true, exclusive: false},  
        function(parent) {
            folder=parent;
        }
        , dirFail);

        //Creating a reader
        var directoryReader = folder.createReader();
        // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
        directoryReader.readEntries(ReaderSucces,readerFail);   

    function ReaderSucces(entries){
        alert("I'm reading")
        var i,len;
        len = entries.length;
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if (entries[i].isDirectory) {
                 var directoryReaderIn = entries[i].createReader();
                directoryReaderIn.readEntries(ReaderSucces,readingFail); 
            }
             if(entries[i].isFile==true)
            {
            entries[i].file(uploadFile, readingFail);
            }
        }
    }

    var fsFail = function(error) {
            alert("failed with error code: " + error.code);
    };                  
    var dirFail = function(error) {
        alert("Directory error code: " + error.code);
    };
    var readerFail = function(error) {
        alert("Reading Directory error code: " + error.code);
    };          
    var readingFail = function (error){
        console.log("Reading Files error code: "+error.code);
    };
}

function uploadFile(file) {
    console.log("Let's upload!!!" + file)
    var target="http://YOUR_IP/upload.php"; //the url to upload on server
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var path = file.fullPath; //"file://"+ 
    var name = file.name;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    ft.upload(path, encodeURI(target), win, fail, { fileName: name, fileKey: "file", mimeType:"text/plain" });
           // var ft = new FileTransfer();
          //ft.upload(file.fullPath, target, win, fail, options);
}
```

The PHP in your server (upload.php)

```
    <?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "\n " ; 
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "\n ";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb\n ";
  echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<\n ";
  if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  } else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); //Save location
    echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
?>
```

It will save all the files (even the ones inside directories) located in your folder. Hope it works.